# Matplotlib xticks values irregular size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am making a plot with matplotlib and I need irregular values for the xtick labels.

I know there is parameter *size*. However, I would like to have values on my x-axis that are two times greater than the values of the labels on the y-axis. With *size* parameter I can only change the font size of the values, but the actual numeric values will still be in proportion 1:1.

Is it possible to make xtick label values in proportion 2:1 with the ytick label values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

fig=plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x)

y_tick_values = ax.get_yticks()
new_x_tick_values = [2 * y for y in y_tick_values]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_x_tick_values)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think I have not expressed myself clearly. I don't won't to change ticks but values below them.

Comment: @Snochacz OK I have edited my answer! Sorry I did not read you question carefully enough. Now the x-axis tick label values will always be twice the y-x axis tick label values.

Comment: @Snochacz please mark as answered if my reply was useful